# Update Account fields from a Desk.com rule trigger

Tags: workflow, account, desk.com

I am new to SFDC and Desk.com. I would like to have an explanation or solution to my problem. The problem is as follows :

I have a checkbox field in Account. I want that when the user checks the field a desk.com rule is triggered. The desk.com rule should change the value of status field at the case.

Is this possible? **Can desk.com rule change fields at a salesforce Account?**